# Reactjs function firing twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently learning Reactjs and want to do a simple Caeser-En/Decryption (shifting characters).

It works fine when the text input is changing but it seems that if the encryption-key is changing (updateRot()), the CaeserShift-function fires twice (or even more often?).

But i can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

```js
class MarkdownEditor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.updateRot = this.updateRot.bind(this);
    this.state = {value: 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
                  rot: 1
                 };
  }
  
  updateRot(e){
    this.setState({
      rot: e.target.value      
    });
  }
  
  handleChange(e){
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value
      });
  }

caesarShift(str, amount){

 var output = '';
 // Go through each character
 for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i ++) {

  // Get the character we'll be appending
  var c = str[i];

  // If it's a letter...
  if (c.match(/[a-z]/i)) {

   // Get its code
   var code = str.charCodeAt(i);
   // Uppercase letters
   if ((code >= 65) && (code <= 90))
    c = String.fromCharCode(((code - 65 + amount) % 26) + 65);

   // Lowercase letters
   else if ((code >= 97) && (code <= 122))
    c = String.fromCharCode(((code - 97 + amount) % 26) + 97);
     
  }
  // Append
  output += c;
 }
 // All done!
  return output
    
};

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="MarkdownEditor">
        <div className="Input">
        <h3>Input</h3>
        <textarea
          rows="2"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          defaultValue={this.state.value}
          />
        </div>
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.rot}</p>
        
        <input className="quantity-input__screen" type="text" defaultValue={this.state.rot} onChange={this.updateRot} />
         
      </div>  
        <div className="Output">
        <h3>Output</h3>
        <textarea
          rows="2"
          className="content"
          value={this.caesarShift(this.state.value, this.state.rot)}
        />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MarkdownEditor />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
.MarkdownEditor div{
  
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
  display:block;
  
}
.MarkdownEditor div textarea{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
  display:block;
 width: 100%;
  overflow-y:auto;/*resets IE*/
  overflow-x:hidden;/*resets IE*/
}
.MarkdownEditor {
  padding-left: 25%;
  padding-right: 25%;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

**EDIT:**
Got the solution!
this.state.rot is no int!

...

> ```
>   caesarShift(str, rot){
>
>       var amount = parseInt(rot)||0;
> ```
>
> ...

Comment: Whenever you are updating the encryption key, you have an onChange event, where you set a state, So whenever you set as state the component is rerenderd and the function is called again

Comment: ok, but why it works fine as long i only change the Input-text? shouldn it be the same effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass parameters to a function through props, you should enclose it in an arrow function otherwise you are essentially calling the function.

Inside `handleChange` you could call `caeserShift` and pass it to the state.

i.e

```
handleChange(e){

    this.setState({
        value: e.target.value,
        encrypted: this.caeserShift(e.target.value, this.state.rot)
    });
}
```

Then you can store this value in the textarea

`value={this.state.encrypted}`

Comment: This way you are not passing the value returned by function but the function itself

Comment: i already tryed this. it seems cant call the caeserShift inside the setState. "TypeError: this.caeserShift is not a function"